# Вынос текста из TEXBOX В отдельную картинку

Tags: c#, изображения, qrcode, qr

Есть код который делает QR картинку и сохраняет её с текстом в формате

[image: Было]

Реализация классная Очень хорошо работает. Но я хочу связать новый Textbox В который будет писаться инф.

А располагать его в числовом формате в самом низу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Посоветуйте как сделать лучше?

```
    private Bitmap ConvertTextToImage(string txt, string fontname, int fontsize, Color bgcolor, Color fcolor, int width, int height)
    {
        var bmp = new Bitmap(181, 81);

        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            var font = new Font("Arial", 10.0f);
            graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(bgcolor), 0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
            graphics.DrawString(txt, font, new SolidBrush(fcolor), new RectangleF(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
        }

        return bmp;
    }
    private Bitmap ConvertTextToImage1(string txt, string fontname, int fontsize, Color bgcolor, Color fcolor, int width, int height)
    {
        var bmp = new Bitmap(181, 30);

        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            var font = new Font("Bookman Old Style", 18.0f);
            graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(bgcolor), 0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
            graphics.DrawString(txt, font, new SolidBrush(fcolor), new RectangleF(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
        }

        return bmp;
    }

    private Bitmap MergeHorizontal(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2)
    {
        var res = new Bitmap(bmp1.Width + bmp2.Width, Math.Max(bmp1.Height, bmp2.Height));

        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(res))
        {
            graphics.DrawImage(bmp1, Point.Empty);
            graphics.DrawImage(bmp2, new Point(bmp1.Width, 0));
        }

        return res;
    }

    private Bitmap MergeVertical(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2)
    {
        var res = new Bitmap(bmp1.Width + bmp2.Width, Math.Max(bmp1.Height, bmp2.Height));

        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(res))
        {
            graphics.DrawImage(bmp1, Point.Empty);
            graphics.DrawImage(bmp2, new Point(bmp1.Width, 0));
        }

        return res;
    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog())
        {
            dialog.Filter = "JPEG files (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.jpe, *.jfif) | *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.jpe; *.jfif";
            dialog.FilterIndex = 2;
            dialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

            if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string savepath = dialog.FileName;

                var bmp1 = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;
                var bmp2 = ConvertTextToImage(textBox1.Text, "Bookman Old Style", 10, Color.White, Color.Black, 180, 100);
                bmp2.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);
                var bmp3 = ConvertTextToImage1(textBox2.Text, "Bookman Old Style", 15, Color.White, Color.Black, 180, 100);
                bmp3.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);
                Bitmap result = MergeHorizontal(bmp1, bmp2);
                result = MergeVertical(result, bmp3);
                result.Save(savepath);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ну так у вас уже всё есть. Мержите 2 картинки, потом полученную ещё с одной, полученной из текста второго Textbox с возможно отличающимися параметрами шрифта и размера.

Comment: Ок, как связать второй  textbox с  private Bitmap ConvertTextToImage ?
Я только как их связать не понимаю

Comment: Вы уже умеете склеивать 2 картинки. Склеиваете 1 и 2, потом то что получилось с 3. У вас есть метод `Merge`, назоваите его `MergeHorizontal`, потом напишите еще один метод `MergeVertical`, дальше думаю сами можете догадаться, что делать.

Comment: Погоди после первого Merge мне нужно будет забрать текст из texbox2  и опять сделать те же самые действия? или можно как то добавить второй текст но под bmp3?

Comment: :D Не получиться 
Math.MaxНи одна из перегрузок метода "Max" не принимает 3 аргументов

Comment: Воспользуйтесь массивом, максимум находится одним методом с помощью Linq

Comment: Максимальное из трех? `Math.Max(a, Math.Max(b,c))` это даже не смешно. :)

Comment: @SmorcIRL Я поправил код. Но.... 
Ошибка CS0103 Имя "res3" не существует в текущем контексте. qr_code C:\QR\qr_code\qr_code\Form1.cs 126 Активные

Comment: Вы запутались в своем коде. Попробуйте переосмыслить, что делают ваши методы и какие значения они возвращают. Должно быть 3 картинки, а у вас 2, метод `MergeHorizontal` вообще ничего не делает. Должно быть что-то типа `Bitmap bmp = MergeHorizontal(res1, res2); MergeVertical(bmp, res3).Save(savepath)`. `MergeHorizontal()` должен приклеивать `res2` к `res1` справа, а `MergeVertical()` - `res3` к `bmp` снизу. Это должно быть просто.

Comment: То есть вам текст надо разбить на 2 части, одна часть будет поворачиваться и приклеиваться справа, вторая не будет поворачиваться и приклеиваться снизу. Если я конечно правильно понял, чего вы хотите добиться.

Comment: Да именно этого я и хочу добиться. Сейчас попробую ещё раз

Comment: Не понимаю я . Не получается :D
Фиг с ним

Comment: Странно, это очень просто, вам точно нужен пример?

Comment: @aepot можно просто вас 
пожалуйста  прокомментировать мой код что бы я понимал порядок действий

Comment: Я дал ответ. Вам помогло?

Comment: Нет( Всё так же.

Comment: @ПавелРоманов я не принял вашу правку в ответ, потому что суть ответа она не меняет. Если вы хотите опубликовать свой финальный код, вы можете создать отдельный ответ. И главная проблема в вашем коде - это вы передаете `width` и `height` в методы, но используете внутри литералы, то есть как вашем изначальном коде, это не логично. Обратите внимание, что я вызваю метод с аргументами `180,100`, это и есть те самые размеры, почитайте мой код внимательней.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не знаю, в чем вы здесь запутались. НО да, у вас какая-то мешанина из методов получилась.

```cs
private Bitmap ConvertTextToImage(string txt, string fontname, int fontsize, Color bgcolor, Color fcolor, int width, int height)
{
    var bmp = new Bitmap(width, height);

    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        var font = new Font(fontname, fontsize);
        graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(bgcolor), 0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
        graphics.DrawString(txt, font, new SolidBrush(fcolor), new RectangleF(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
    }

    return bmp;
}

private Bitmap Merge(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2)
{
    var res = new Bitmap(bmp1.Width + bmp2.Width, Math.Max(bmp1.Height, bmp2.Height));

    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(res))
    {
        graphics.DrawImage(bmp1, Point.Empty);
        graphics.DrawImage(bmp2, new Point(bmp1.Width, 0));
    }

    return res;
}

private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog())
    {
        dialog.Filter = "JPEG files (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.jpe, *.jfif) | *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.jpe; *.jfif";
        dialog.FilterIndex = 2;
        dialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string savepath = dialog.FileName;

            var bmp1 = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;
            var bmp2 = ConvertTextToImage(textBox1.Text, "Bookman Old Style", 10, Color.White, Color.Black, 181, 30);
            bmp2.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);
            var bmp3 = ConvertTextToImage(textBox2.Text, "Bookman Old Style", 15, Color.White, Color.Black, 181, 30);
            bmp3.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);
            Bitmap result = Merge(bmp1, bmp2);
            result = Merge(result, bmp3);
            result.Save(savepath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
    }
}
```